# Intuition behind polar coordinate to find limit in multivariate calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, intuition, polar-coordinates

Find limit using the polar coordinate for the function at $(0,0)$
$$ 
f(x,y) = \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} 
$$

I started using $x = r\cos(\theta),\, y = r\sin(\theta)$

Then $(x,y) \to (0,0) \implies r \to 0$

Then we get as the following
$$ 
f\bigl(r\cos(\theta),\, r\sin(\theta)\bigr) 
= \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) 
$$

Now I have no idea how to proceed from here. Some of the ideas from youtube videos I had was: $\theta$ is a free variable and the limit is more like spiraling into $(0,0)$.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening? What is the idea behind $r \to 0$?

Comment: If you take the limit at the origin, imagine a circle that shrinks to a point.

Comment: Why would I imagine a circle? Does that mean $\theta$ is always changing? I am really not getting the idea of $\theta$

Comment: It's not that $\theta$ is changing, but rather $\theta$ is arbitrary. For any given path $\theta$ is fixed to some function of $r$ - for straight line spokes those are constant values. But for a limit to exist its value must not only exist along all paths but they must also all agree with each other. What the $\theta$ left behind represents is that the limit is dependent on the path taken, and explicitly every straight line path in this case has different values for their limits.

Comment: Let $r_n \to 0$ then for $r_1$ we are changing $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ then if we take $r_2$ we are again taking $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and so on before we reach origin. Is this the idea?

Comment: @NinadMunshi how does $sin(\theta)+cos(\theta)$ represent that it is dependent on paths?

Comment: Because if you approach the origin along lines forming different angles $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis, you're getting different results. For example, along the line $y=x$ you have $\theta = \pi/4$ and the limit would be $\sqrt{2}$, but along $y=\sqrt{3}x$ you have $\theta = \pi/3$ and the limit would be $(1+\sqrt{3})/2$. It's important to note that using polar coordinates is not the same thing as "choosing a path", it actually means looking at the same thing from a different point of view (which may be helpful to identify paths with different limits).

Answer (score 2):

If you want use polar coordinates, then with $(x,y)\mapsto (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ for $r\in {\bf R}_{+}^{*}$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi[$, then $$f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\frac{r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}{\sqrt{r^{2}(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)}}=\cos\theta+\sin\theta.$$

- If $\theta=\pi$, then $f_1(\theta):=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\cos\theta+\sin\theta=-1$.
- If $\theta=\pi/2$, then $f_2(\theta):=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\cos\theta+\sin\theta=1$.

If $f$ has limit $\ell\in {\bf R}$ at $(0,0)$, then the composite functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ they have to have the same limit $\ell$ at $0$, but it is imposible as it was show above. Therefore,  the $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

The limit $\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$

exists if $f$ evaluated every point in a small neighborhood of the origin has is in a small neighborhood.  We can get more formal with $\epsilon-\delta$ balls, but this idea is sufficient.

If we convert to polar coordinate and then choose a small value of $r,$ then all values of $(r,\theta)$ will be close to each other.  If the limit exists, all values of $f(r,\theta)$ will be close to each other regardless of our choice for $\theta.$

In this case $f(r,\theta) = \cos\theta + \sin \theta$

$f(r,\theta)$ could be as big a $\sqrt {2}$ and as small as $-\sqrt{2}$ no matter how small we choose $r$ to be.  This is not a small neighborhood.